# Setting Passwordless ssh when a home directory is shared with NFS

Tags: nfs, openssh

I have two nodes (master and slave) where the home directory of the master is shared via NFS with the slave node. I have created an ssh key and used 'ssh-copy-id' to add the public key to 'authorized_keys'.

The passwordless ssh works from the slave to the master, but not from the master to slave as I get "agent admitted failure to signing using key".

I think it may be an issue with file permissions but it is tricky since ~/.ssh folder is shared using NFS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you have SELinux enabled, you may have to enable NFS mounted home directories via:

```
setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs=true
```

I had this problem on RHEL, and found the solution in /var/log/messages:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from read access on the file
>   authorized_keys.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (89.3
>   confidence) suggests
>   ******************#012#012If you want to allow use to nfs home dirs#012Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the
>   'use_nfs_home_dirs' boolean.#012You can read 'None' man page for more
>   details.#012Do#012setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1#012#012*****

Comment: I don't know if this is THE right answer, but it is pretty darned good advice in general. 1. Suspect SELINUX when anything soes not work as expected 2) Read /var/log/messages. I learned from this one +1

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate the key in master or slave?
Try this on both master and slave:

```
chmod go-w $HOME $HOME/.ssh
sudo chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown 'username' $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

"username" is the name of the user you need to enable ssh.

Try this if the above method fails:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub USERNAME@HOSTNAME.local
```

Enter this command from slave.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that didn't help. I have noticed something weird, the first ssh attempt I get the "agent admitted failure" error, however ssh works after subsequent ssh. I am creating the key from in the master